# Normal Sylow $p$-subgroup of a normal subgroup

Tags: finite-groups, sylow-theory, normal-subgroups

Any hints for the following question - I am sure that I am missing something very simple here.

$K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$. If $P$ is a normal subgroup of $K$, show that it is also a normal subgroup of $G$.

$G$ is a finite group

Comment: Use Sylow's theorem on the size and conjugacy of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $g \in G$, then $g^{-1}Pg \leq K$ since $K$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: That was it - one can then show that $gPg^{-1}$ is a Sylow-p Subgroup and because $P$ is the unique such one in $K$ everything follows